# Ignoring all filetypes underneath a directory .gitignore

Tags: git

I'm trying to ignore all of a certain type of file within a directory recursively. For example, if I have the folder build and underneath it are other folders, say:

```
-Build
\-Folder1
|-Folder2
|-Folder3
```

How would I go about removing all .class files in every directory underneath build?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a `.gitignore` file in the build directory and put `*.class` in it. You can read more about Git Ignore files [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files).

If the `.class` files are already being tracked, then you need to remove the files so git doesn't track them. `git rm --cached '*.class'` will cause the files to stop being tracked, but leave them on your local file system.

Comment: I did this and it looks like it only ignored the files that were directly underneath build. It seems this expression doesn't do anything with the files in folder1, folder2, and folder3.

Comment: @MichaelDelany I don't see that behavior. Are the `.class` files under those folders already tracked? (Have they ever been committed or added?). A .gitignore won't ignore things that are already set to be tracked.

Comment: Okay, looks like I fixed it. I just untracked the directory everything seems to have worked. Thank you